# How Regex works with special character

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to get an amount from a string. but the dollar sign not comes. what is wrong am I doing.

```
a = 'kamsd;as $ 410 005 aksdkla 5662 ajsdnjkas d 526 asdn526'
find = re.findall(r"\$*[\d]", a)
print(''.join(find))
```

my output is - `4100055662526526`
I want - `$4100055662526526`

Comment: Is there an answer that fits ?

Answer (score 0):

Your regex does not match your data.

You made the `$` occureable 0 to n times - *directly before a number* - not `directly before a space followed by a number`:

```
import re

a = 'kamsd;as $ 410 005 aksdkla 5662 ajsdnjkas d 526 asdn526'
find = re.findall(r"\$?(?: )?[\d]+", a)  # grab the $ with the space for numbers
print(''.join(find))
```

should work:

```
$ 410 005 5662 526526
```

Answer (score -2):

It seems that you just want dollar sign + every digit, so simplify the regex `[$\d]`

```
a = 'kamsd;as $ 410 005 aksdkla 5662 ajsdnjkas d 526 asdn526'
find = re.findall(r"[$\d]", a)
print(''.join(find)) # $4100055662526526
```

---

If you want to keep separate groups of digits just add the `+` to get `[$\d]+`

```
a = 'kamsd;as $ 410 005 aksdkla 5662 ajsdnjkas d 526 asdn526'
find = re.findall(r"[$\d]+", a)
print(' '.join(find))  # $ 410 005 5662 526 526
```